# Laravel post request from another domain database error

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo, laravel-5.5

When I trying to make POST request to my API from another website, that uses sqlite, I am getting wery strange error on my API server, here is some trace:

```
production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'onclinic.sqlite' {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 1049): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'onclinic.sqlite' at D:\\OSPanel\\domains\\onclinic-engine\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 1049): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'onclinic.sqlite' at D:\\OSPanel\\domains\\onclinic-engine\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:43)
D:\\OSPanel\\domains\\onclinic-engine\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php(64): Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', '', Array)
D:\\OSPanel\\domains\\onclinic-engine\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php(43): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=127....', 'root', '', Array)
D:\\OSPanel\\domains\\onclinic-engine\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127....', Array, Array)
D:\\OSPanel\\domains\\onclinic-engine\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory.php(183): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
```

I really do not understand, why my API server failidng because of sqlite databse, if all config is set up to use mysql

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

### Update

All work fine if I'm sending request from postman, but GuzzleHttp gets me troubles.

Comment: Doesn't the error message help you? `Unknown database 'onclinic.sqlite'`

Comment: I am using MySQL on my API server, but when making request from another website that uses sqlite, for some reason my API server also trying to find sqlite database to connect except of mysql. Problem not in inpossibility to find sqlite DB, but why API server even tries to connect to sqlite, not to mysql.

Comment: I guess your configs are not being read the way you think they are.

Comment: set `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` in your .env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the problem.
Laravel using PHP environment, so if laravel config not cached, My API server getting values from .env file of API client, so when I sending request to API server on local machine, it using database name from Environment set when API client beign initialized.
to avoid this simly cache your config on server.